# Text box too small in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a textbox next to my plot, using matplotlib. The problem is that the textbox does not appear fully next to plots. Even if I maximize the plots, its the same problem

Is it possible to somehow resize my plot area and make it smaller so that textbox is visbile, and area ratio is carried forward even when i maximize the plots

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr_len = 932826
x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=4496, size=arr_len)
y = np.random.uniform(low=-74, high=492, size=arr_len)
z = np.random.uniform(low=-30, high=97, size=arr_len)

# Check points
bin_x = 10
bin_y = 10
x1 = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), bin_x)
y1 = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), bin_y)


def return_val(x, y, z, x1, y1, i, j):
    idx = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(x > x1[i - 1], x < x1[i]), np.logical_and(y > y1[j - 1], y < y1[j]))
    if np.count_nonzero(idx) == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        # print('X range', x[idx].min(), x[idx].max())
        # print('Y range', y[idx].min(), y[idx].max())
        # print('Z range', z[idx].min(), z[idx].max())
        # plt.plot(x[idx], y[idx], '.')
        # plt.close()
        return np.mean(z[idx])


z1 = np.zeros((len(x1), len(y1)))
for i in range(1, len(x1)):
    for j in range(1, len(y1)):
        z1[i - 1, j - 1] = return_val(x, y, z, x1, y1, i, j)

z1 = z1.transpose()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = ax.pcolormesh(x1, y1, z1)
# cbar = plt.colorbar(img)
textbox = '\n'.join([
    'All plot description goes here: ',
    'File Name: ',
    '',
    'Folder path: ',
    'List of big files processed: ',
    'Dataset name: ',
    '',
    'Filter: ',
    'Grouping: ',
    'Files which are bigger in size than 2000 GB : ',
    '',
    '...',
    '...',
    '...',
])
bbox = dict(boxstyle='square', facecolor='lavender', alpha=0.5)
fig.text(1, 1, textbox, fontsize=10, transform=ax.transAxes, bbox=bbox,
         verticalalignment='top')
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.tight_layout();plt.show()` If you add this, the text box will be included and the graph will automatically shrink.

Comment: @r-beginners:  I tried to add those commands at the end, but it did not seem to help

Comment: Please add it at the very end. Is MPL up to date?

Comment: figure text objects are not included in tight_layout or constrained_layout calculations because those routines work to make *axes* properly spaced. If you put text on the figure, which axes should move to make space for it? However, if you do `ax.text()`, constrained_layout and tight_layout should work fine.   (also, 95% of the time constrained_layout is a better choice than tight_layout).